# How do you draw a basic line with ConTeXt and METAFUN?

Tags: context, line, metafun

I was able to draw a basic line, however I am still have this feeling of having hit another **pebcak…**

This is my line:

```
\startMPcode
    path line ; line := (0mm,0cm)--(5cm,0cm) ;
    draw line withpen pensquare scaled 2pt 
    withcolor yellow;       
\stopMPcode
```

Perhaps it would better drawing a rectangle but it looked to me even more convoluted. Unfortunately the few basic notions about shapes and numbers come from HTML/CSS and here come other problems…

**What did I try to achieve but I failed:**

1. Failed to setup absolute coordinate since the offset of the line is not aligned with a framed text above.
2. Failed to setup the width a % of the column

How do you draw a basic line with ConTeXt and METAFUN?

Comment: What you have there draws indeed a line. Can you be a bit more explicit (perhaps with a (handdrawn) picture) on what you want to do? How do you intend to use the line that you draw?

Comment: Can you please give us a complete [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that shows the problem?

Comment: Thank you guys, I wonder if there are better methods to draw a line. It may look trivial for you, but it was very hard for me connecting the "dots" from the Metafun manual, and I feel like I did it the wrong way.

Comment: Did you see https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/defineMPinstance and https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/uniqueMPgraphic?